# Xamarin Forms How do I use a button on a content page to switch to another Navigation Page

Tags: xamarin.forms

In My app, I've created Content pages wrapped in navigation pages and added those navigation pages to a TabbedPage.

What I want is to use the TabbedPage at the top as sort of a menu to navigate around my app. This sems to all be working fine, except I want to add a button on some content pages that can jump around to another one of the content/navigation pages.

How can I "Select" another of the navigation pages within the TabbedPage?

Edit: Adding existing code...

So I have in MainPage.xaml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:JobAidTurbo.Views"
            x:Class="JobAidTurbo.Views.MainPage">
    <TabbedPage.Children>

        <NavigationPage Title="Main">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:MainMenu />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage Title="Cheeses">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:Cheeses />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
    </TabbedPage>
```

In MainPage.xaml.cs is:

```
using System;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace JobAidTurbo.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object, int>(this, "click", (sender, arg) =>
            {
                CurrentPage = Children[arg];
            });
        }
    }

}
```

In MainMenu.xaml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="JobAidTurbo.Views.MainMenu"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Text="Cheeses"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                BackgroundColor="Blue"
                    TextColor="White"
                    FontSize="36"
                    WidthRequest="350"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                    Clicked="Cheeses_Clicked"
                                        />
            <Button Text="Meats"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                BackgroundColor="Blue"
                    TextColor="White"
                    FontSize="36"
                    WidthRequest="350"
                    HeightRequest="200"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="1"
                    />
</Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And in MainMenu.xaml.cs I Have:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace JobAidTurbo.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainMenu : ContentPage
    {
        public MainMenu ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }

        private void Cheeses_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<Object, int>(this, "click", 2);
            //2 is the num of the contentPage that you want to select


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

You can use `MessagingCenter` .Refer to the following code.

> in the button clickEvent

```
button.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
  {
     MessagingCenter.Send<Object,int>(this,"click",2); 
     //2 is the num of the contentPage that you want to select

   };
```

> in the TabbedPage(constructor)

```
public MyTabbedPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //. . .

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object,int>(this, "click", (sender,arg) =>
        {               
            CurrentPage = Children[arg];              
        });
```

Now the tabbedPage will select the third contentPage whenyou click the button.

For more detail about `MessagingCenter` you can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center).

Comment: It did not work. Please bear in mind I'm very new to Xamarin Forms. I'll update above with my code